# How to add trailing slash "/" to all internal urls with an sql query

Tags: sql, wordpress, url, hyperlink

I recently changed the permalinks of a WP website to contain a trailing slash "/" at the end.

There's a lot of custom made internal linking between thousands of articles.

I'd prefer not to use redirects, but rather to add a slash at the end of all existing internal urls of the entire site.

Is there a way I can do this with an sql query?

I'm not a developer so an exact command will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_concat.asp)?

Comment: CONCAT is not a solution to this. I don't have a list of those urls and they are thousands, maybe tens of thousands. I need to add a slash to all of them at once.

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(mycolumn, '/') FROM mytable` *would* add a slash to all entries from the table – or if you want that persistent you could do `UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn=CONCAT(mycolumn, '/')`. If that's not what you want then you should be more specific in your question.